# Ionic Framework Error - SlideBox does not swipe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

Hello and thank you for taking the time for reading this.

I'm trying to install the SlideBox on the tab-dash.html page and coming into some errors. I'm following the instructions on the website and can't seem to get it working.

This is the error I get when I debug in the browser:

```
ionic.bundle.js:25510 ReferenceError: fade is not defined

at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:6:11)
at invoke (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17630:17)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17638:27)
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22194:28
at self.appendViewElement (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56747:24)
at Object.switcher.render (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:54859:41)
at Object.switcher.init (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:54779:20)
at self.render (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56607:14)
at self.register (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56565:10)
at updateView (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:62210:23) <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash" class="view-container tab-content" nav-view="active" nav-view-transition="android">(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:25510(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:22289invokeLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:21832nodeLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:21330compositeLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:20721publicLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:20596tabSelected @ ionic.bundle.js:63739Scope.$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:28863Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:29131done @ ionic.bundle.js:23544completeRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:23716requestLoaded @ ionic.bundle.js:23657
```

---

here is my tab-dash.html

```
<ion-content class="padding">

<ion-slides  options="options" slider="data.slider">
 <ion-slide-page>
<div class="box blue"><h1>BLUE</h1></div>
</ion-slide-page>
<ion-slide-page>
<div class="box yellow"><h1>YELLOW</h1></div>
</ion-slide-page>
<ion-slide-page>
<div class="box pink"><h1>PINK</h1></div>
</ion-slide-page>
</ion-slides>

// the rest of the page ...
```

---

Here is my controllers.js (when I insert this code the whole page disappears and when I remove the effect: fade, line of code it goes back to the slider without swipe capabilities)

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
$scope.options = {
loop: false,
effect: fade,
speed: 500,
}
$scope.data = {};
$scope.$watch('data.slider', function(nv, ov) {
$scope.slider = $scope.data.slider;
})
})


// other controllers here ...
```

Any tips on how I can get this working?

I really appreciate you guys helping me out as this is very important to me.

Thank you again.

Sincerely,

Adam

Comment: Are you using Ionic 1.x or 2?

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I fixed it. So some reason when you add the SlideBox directive you must ionic serve the app again in the terminal. I hope this lasts. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

So some reason when you add the SlideBox directive you must ionic serve the app again in the terminal. I hope this lasts.